# PHP pair two array

Tags: php, arrays

How do you grab two arrays and list them as key pairs separated by commas.

```
Array1
    'key1a'=>'value'
    'key2a'=>'value'
    'key3a'=>'value'

Array2
    'key7b'=>'value'
    'key8b'=>'value'
    'key9b'=>'value'
```

Desired output:

```
key1a = key7b, key2a = key8b, key3a = key9b
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$new_Array = array_combine(array_keys($Array1), array_keys($Array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newarr = array_combine(array_keys($arr1), array_keys($arr2));
```

This should do given that $arr1 and $arr2 are the same length.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array('key1a'=>'value',
'key2a'=>'value',
'key3a'=>'value');

$array2 = array('key7b'=>'value',
'key8b'=>'value',
'key9b'=>'value');

$keys = array_combine(array_keys($array1),array_keys($array2));
foreach($keys as $k => $k2) echo " $k = $k2".($k2==end($keys)?'':',');
```

[DEMO VIEW](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gV9Df2)

Comment: This is what I'm looking for but I was hoping not to use a any loops.

Comment: You can do a function which return the loop results all times

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arr1 as $i => $val){
    foreach($arr2 as $j => $val2){
    echo $i . " = " . $j . ", ";
    }
}
```

This works, though probably not what you're looking for (because you commented that you were trying to do it without loops?) Keep in mind, `array_combine()` is a PHP5 function.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of this:

```
implode(', ', array_map(create_function('$k1,$k2', 'return $k1 . " = :" . $k2;'), array_keys($array1), array_keys($array2)))
```